# Why is FTP (in-built in OS) faster in Linux than in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, throughput

For a throughput testing through FTP, I used FTP server in Windows as well as Linux platform.

But in Windows I got the speed around 18Mbps but in Linux I am getting the speed as 40-45Mbps, which is more than double.

Can anybody please explain me the reasons behind it and what are the overheads and all.

Comment: Which FTP servers?

Comment: In built in windows7 which we enable from Internet Information services

Comment: I would guess Windows built in FTP is a) legacy code, b) not optimized for large (jumbo packets) and C)... well try something else. No one uses Windows FTP anymore when Filezilla and dozens of other better FTP clients are free and more friendly.

Comment: Thanks.But what if i use filezilla both in windows and linux? would there be any difference in speed?

Comment: Windows ftp support is just utter crap.

Comment: "But what if i use filezilla both in windows and linux? would there be any difference in speed?" - Can't you test and compare, just as you did so above?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that Linux has faster implementation of TCP/IP stack.

Also, Windows machines often run an anti-virus software that scans all file activity in real time which can slow down file operations in FTP server. Linux machines usually don't run such AV software :-)